# Store temp data in Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have read that Agents can store data, what I would like to do is store data per request, similar to a user session but that would be accessible inside models. Ideas are welcome.

Comment: Without more context it is hard to tell what the best solution would be. Would you mind expanding a bit on the problem you are actually trying to solve?

Comment: In Phoenix all session data is stored in `Plug.Conn` structure. In functional languages it is usually good idea to make your data explicit and not hide it. But as @PatrickOscity said. We need more context and maybe even code samples.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/introduction-to-mix.html covers some of the ideas around storing data in an agent.  Probably you should work though the tutorial first and then when you've got a more specific question post it.

Comment: For example how should I store a shopping cart

Comment: You're asking for a specific answer to a general question @BorisBarroso. What kinds of data do you need to store in the shopping cart?  Customer id?  Does the shopping cart need a unique ID in case you want to persist it?  Etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Well I thought I could use sessions to store this kind of data but I'm using Guardian (Json web token) with an API and sessions did not work